# Function Constructor - add function using prototype gives - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, object-construction, function-constructor

I tried adding a function `y()` into the object constructor `x` using prototype chaining. It results to an `unexpected` error:

> Unexpected token `{`

```js
function x(a, b) {
  this.a = a
  this.b = b
}
x.prototype.y(){
  console.log('hello')
}
```

I want the function x as:

```
function x(a, b) {
  this.a = a; 
  this.b = b; 

  y() 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not assigning `y` to a function. Your syntax is invalid. Instead, use an [anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_expression_(function_expression)):

`x.prototype.y = function() {...}`

See working example below:

```js
function x(a, b) {
  this.a = a
  this.b = b
}

x.prototype.y = function() {
  console.log('hello');
}

let a = new x(1, 2);
a.y();
```

If you wish for the method to be *static* you can omit the `prototype`:

```js
function x(a, b) {
  this.a = a
  this.b = b
}

x.y = function() {
  console.log('hello');
}

x.y();
```

Comment: I want the function x as -

ƒ x(a, b) { this.a = a ; this.b = b ; y() }

Comment: @MonicaAcha then don't use `prototype` see the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can't use that syntax - you need to declare it like this:

```
x.prototype.y = function() {
    console.log("Hello");
};
```

This is because you're assigning an anonymous function to a property on an object - it's just like you'd do it in a constructor. Here's a full example of your code:

```js
function x(a, b) {
  this.a = a
  this.b = b
}
x.prototype.y = function() {
  console.log("Hello");
};

var anX = new x("a", "b");
anX.y();
```

Comment: I want the function x as -

ƒ x(a, b) { this.a = a ; this.b = b ; y() }

Comment: @MonicaAcha So you just want to assign the function inside the object constructor? Just do `this.y = function() { console.log("Hello"); };`.